# OpenLDAP Invalid Credentials

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, ubuntu-9.04

I'm setting up an OpenLDAP server to authenticate users in a domain on Ubuntu 9.04.

What's interesting/strange is that in the newest version of openldap for Ubuntu, the default is not to use the /etc/ldap/slapd.conf file - instead it stores its configs in cn=config in the database (this has lead to some headaches trying to follow tutorials that specify slapd.conf instead of the newer version).

Whenever I try to add to the database using ldapadd, it returns ldap_bind (49) Invalid Credentials (even when I'm sure I'm using the right password).

The database doesn't have anything in it yet, so starting from scratch isn't a problem, I've just encountered this several times (even after reconfiguring slapd). What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if OpenLDAP returns subcodes on error 49's like Active Directory does.  AD returns a subtype of the error code for bad password, versus bad DN.

Are you confident the DN is correct?

Comment: +1 For coming up with the same answer I figured out. I was using the wrong credentials - should have been using cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com instead of cn=admin,cn=config. Dumb mistake. Easy fix though.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying "-x" on the commandline.  By default, the LDAP tools use SASL authentication, -x specifies "simple authentication".

Comment: The command I'm using to try to add some example entries in the db:
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f example.com.ldif.

-x disables SALS authentication, and -W makes sure it prompts for a the administrator password (which I enter). Still no joy. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hmm.  I am not familiar with configurations that don't use slapd.conf so I am not entirely sure where to go.  Off the top of my head I would try running slapcat to print out the ldif of the database directly and verify that the rootdn matches what you are entering for your bind.